# Replace em Data dentro de um FOR

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Quero retornar os últimos 12 meses, o dia deve vir como 01 e  preciso mês e ano.
ex:

```
2014-12-01
2014-11-01
```

OBS: coloquei yyyy-mm-dd apenas por um padrão meu.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @Data_Atual DATE
SET @count = 0
WHILE (@count < 12)
BEGIN
   SET @count = (@count + 1)    -- count++

   SET @Data_Atual = DATEADD(month, -@count, GETDATE()) --as 12 datas


   print @Data_Atual

END
```

O problema que hoje dia 08 esta retornando:

```
2014-12-08
2014-11-08
2014-10-08
2014-09-08
2014-08-08
2014-07-08
2014-06-08
2014-05-08
2014-04-08
2014-03-08
2014-02-08
2014-01-08
```

e quero fazer um replace na dia para 01, tanto faz a forma. mas preciso que ela continue sendo um tipo DATE pois vou utilizar ela em um select ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mantendo seu algoritmo, adicione esta linha que setará em `@Data_Atual` o primeiro dia do mês do próprio `@Data_Atual`:

```
SET @Data_Atual = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @Data_Atual), 0)
```

Comment: Grande café, parabéns, funcionou, depois dessa vou até beber um cafezinho..